# Flask server starting issue - Address already in use

Tags: python, flask, web-frameworks

I am complete noobie in python web framework and just started to learn flask.
I am following a youtube tutorial in which I began to write these lines in `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'INDEX'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Initially the code is complied and the server start running in `localhost:5000` . Later I stopped the server by using `ctrl+c` and made changed a line to `app.run(debug=True)`.
When I tried to compile the file again, It's showing the below result

```
    harsha20599@harsha20599-Inspro:~/python/flask/flaskapp$ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 11, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/home/harsha20599/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/harsha20599/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 720, in run_simple
    s.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Can I force restart the server manually or change the server to the vacant port address ?

Comment: I think if you try `app.run(debug=True, port=0)` it will pick a random free port. Alternatively, choose one yourself that nothing else is currently using.

Comment: what happens if you go to this address in a browser, do you see your app ? in this case, the thread is still alive

Comment: This happens to me when  i press ctl-z instead of ctl-c by mistake. I usually launch on a different port as specified above or restart my terminal/command if it annoys me or ive done it 5 times in a row. Im fairly certain this has to do with sockets not being closed properly. Your server wont be running but the socket is still open.

Answer (score 3):

The option to change the server port is exposed in the `run` method of the application. The argument is named `port`, so you could change call `app.run(port=5001)` to tell the app to listen on port 5001.

See [the Flask class documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.run) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill all other processes which may be running on your server using:

```py
$ sudo fuser -k xxxx/tcp
# Replace xxxx with your port name (5000)
```

Restart your flask server.